# Implement Euclidean Ricci Flow on 3D surface

Tags: ricci-flow

I am not majoring in mathematics but right now I'm trying to work on a 3D surface.

I want to apply Euclidean Ricci flow to do the conformal mapping using Mathematica, at first with simple ellipsoid shapes then later I could go in for more complex geometries.

Has anyone here ever worked on this kind of task before?

Comment: Why choose a tough topography? Can you do it for an ellipsoid?

Comment: Anything would do. I just want to understand the concept and how to implement it.

Comment: Then, I would simplify the question for you. Hope it is ok.

Comment: Okay, thanks. @Narasimham